# How to add a remind me again action to web push?

Tags: service-worker, web-push, service-worker-events

When showing my web push notifications, I'm adding an action in my options so user can ask to get notified again in 30 minutes.

```
  const options = {
    ...,
    actions: [
        {
          action: 'remind-action',
          title: 'Remind again in 30',
          icon: '/remind.png'
        }
    ],
    ....
  }
```

and then I handle the action in service worker:

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
  if (!event.action) return

  switch (event.action) {
    ...
    case 'remind-action':
            event.notification.close()
            event.waitUntil(
                new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

                    setTimeout(() => {

                        const options = {
                                ...
                                actions: [
                                    {
                                        action: 'remind-action',
                                        title: 'Remind again in 30',
                                        icon: '/remind.png'
                                    }
                                ],
                                ...
                        }

                        self.registration.showNotification('Reminder', options)
                        resolve(true)

                    }, 30 * 60 * 1000)

                })
            )

      break
  }
})
```

If only there was a way to re-emit the push event.

The issue with the above code is that it won't show the notification after 30 minutes, however if I set the timeout to 1 minute it works just fine.

I think some where Chrome is ignoring `event.waitUntill` and killing the `setTimeout`.

What is causing this and how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

The browser will automatically and on purpose throttle your setTimeouts to prevent abuse and eg. tracking of the user. Put it another way, you cannot implement what you want solely on the client side.

To show the notification again (reliably), you need to send it again from the server. You would ofc inform the server that the user wants to be reminded in x minutes or so.